# Making a Python-Telegram-Bot persistent

Tags: python, heroku, persistence, python-telegram-bot

I recently coded a simple telegram bot using the python-telegram-bot library, and deployed this bot on Heroku.
Now i'm looking for an effective way to make the bot persistent, allowing it to store Bot_data and user_data between runs.
I took a look at the persistence classes the library offers and i understood that PicklePersistence would not work with heroku's "ephemeral" hard drive.
My question is, how can i implement the bot's persistence to make it work on heroku? Should i 
 give up storing the bot_data and change the design to rely on an external database where to store the data i need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest and try to implement a database for your telegram bot. This will take your bot to a next level, where you would also be able to connect a webapp to the database and add more functionality there.

To start you can try the free tier of [MongoDB atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) database. You could use this database to store your data and get it when needed.

You could also look at other database solutions of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, a followup question: in my implementation i need to store some whole objects such as messages i receive. How would you store something like that in a database? I would need to serialize it in order to store it?

Comment: If you would use MongoDB in Python you would use [Pymongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html) to communicate with your database. As you can read more about in the tutorial, you would go ahead and create a dict with the data you want to store (chatId, userId, timestamp, message etc.) and you can use insert to send it to your database. You can also use Pymongo to find elements in your collection to use for your bot.

Comment: Thank you so much, i think MongoDB is actually the way to go because it would let me keep the abstraction of a dictionary which is the same way data is stored in bot_data and user_data. So the implementation wouldn't even need to change that much. Again Thank you.

Comment: Hello Samuel, would you mind sharing your architecture? I am facing the same challenge and would be great to learn from you. I am interested specifically on how you load data into the .context variables on bot startup from the database

Comment: @OrenPinsky look into the python-telegram-bot spec. It's very clear there how to use these variables.