# My variable gets refreshed to 0 when getting to another elif statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, variables, telegram-bot

The problem is, that my variable does not get plus up, it just becomes "0" and pluses another value.
Don't get worried, my code is okay. I get 0 on every new ELIF. BTW, I don't use `global` statement, cause i am developing multi club bot.

here is my code:

```
def pointsDB():
    dPoints = 0
    return dPoints

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def startingTest(message):
    dPoints = pointsDB()
    while message.text == str(q21s1.text) or str(q21s2.text) or str(q21s3.text) or str(q21s4.text):
        if message.chat.type == "private":
            if message.text == "Начать тест":
                print(UserName + " начал тест")
                markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ИНСТРУКЦИЯ".format(
                message.from_user, bot.get_me()), reply_markup=markup)
                time.sleep(1.5)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Группа #1".format(
                message.from_user, bot.get_me()), reply_markup=q1)
                print(UserName + " " +  str(dPoints) + " points")
                break
            elif message.text == str(q1s1.text) or message.text == str(q1s2.text) or message.text == str(q1s3.text) or message.text == str(q1s4.text):
                if message.text == str(q1s1.text):
                    dPoints += 0
                    print(UserName + " " + message.text)
                elif message.text == str(q1s2.text):
                    dPoints += 1
                    print(UserName + " " + message.text)
                elif message.text == str(q1s3.text):
                    dPoints += 2
                    print(UserName + " " + message.text)
                elif message.text == str(q1s4.text):
                    dPoints += 3
                    print(UserName + " " + message.text)
                markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
                time.sleep(1)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы ответили на 1 из 21 вопросов".format(
                message.from_user, bot.get_me()), reply_markup=markup)
                time.sleep(2)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Группа #2".format(
                message.from_user, bot.get_me()), reply_markup=q2)
                print(UserName + " " +  str(dPoints) + " points")
                break

            elif message.text == str(q2s1.text) or message.text == str(q2s2.text) or message.text == str(q2s3.text) or message.text == str(q2s4.text):
                if message.text == str(q2s1.text):
                    dPoints += 0
                    print(UserName + " " + message.text)
                elif message.text == str(q2s2.text):
                    dPoints += 1
                    print(UserName + " " + message.text)
                elif message.text == str(q2s3.text):
                    dPoints += 2
                    print(UserName + " " + message.text)
                elif message.text == str(q2s4.text):
                    print(UserName + " " +  str(dPoints) + " points")
                    dPoints += 3
                    print(UserName + " " + message.text)
                markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
                time.sleep(1)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы ответили на 2 из 21 вопросов".format(
                message.from_user, bot.get_me()), reply_markup=markup)
                time.sleep(2)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Группа #3".format(
                message.from_user, bot.get_me()), reply_markup=q3)
                print(UserName + " " + str(dPoints) + " points")
                break
```

The output i get is:

"UserName" 0 Points

"UserName" 2 Points (can be 0,1,2,3)

"UserName" 0 Points

"Username" 3 Points (can be 0,1,2,3)

Comment: What is the purpose of the `import` statement?

Comment: Oh, i forgot to delete it. I will edit it now. The `import` statement was for connecting another .py file.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `pointsDB()` function at all?  It just always gives you 0, and you don't persist the value anywhere.  Is it supposed to store the points value in some sort of database?

Comment: The condition in your `while` loop doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @Samwise kind of. I could do the same just in `def startingTest(message): dPoints = 0`. It does the same

Comment: @chepner isn't it a loop? What can i do instead, so it works?

Comment: Each time your function is called, it's getting a single message, and it doesn't "remember" anything between messages.  The loop is pointless because it only ever runs once.

Comment: @Samwise how can i make it, so it "remembers"? Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60610369/making-a-python-telegram-bot-persistent